# How to get AppSettings in Views?

Tags: servicestack

When using ServiceStack how to use IAppSettings in views to get values?

I am injecting IAppSettings in controllers and other places but how to access values inside views code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### AppSettings in Razor Views

[AppSettings is a property of Razor's ViewPageBase](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/8af73b3b5916bd413d66de763e9381761784644c/src/ServiceStack.Razor/ViewPageBase.cs#L382) so you can access it simply with:

```
base.AppSettings
```

### [AppSettings are First Class](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/AppSettings#first-class-appsettings)

You also don't need to inject `IAppSettings` into the Container since if it's not already registered ServiceStack will automatically be register it in the IOC for you.